# What does it mean for pullbacks to preserve monomorphisms?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, definition

If two arrows $f_A : A \to C$, $f_B : B \to C$ are monomorphisms, then their pullback arrows $p_A : P \to A$, $p_B : P \to B$ are monomorhisms too. Is that what is meant by pullbacks preserving monomorphisms?

Comment: Correct. Actually, you can conclude $p_A$ is a monomorphism if $f_B$ is.

Comment: @ZhenLin: This is an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible meanings:

- For any pullback square as below,
  $$\require{AMScd}
  \begin{CD}
  X' @>>> X \\
  @VVV @VVV \\
  Y' @>>> Y
  \end{CD}$$
  if $X \to Y$ is a monomorphism, then $X' \to Y'$ is also a monomorphism.
- For any commutative diagram of the form below,
  $$\begin{CD}
  X' @>>> X \\
  @VVV @VVV \\
  Y' @>>> Y \\
  @VVV @VVV \\
  S' @>>> S
  \end{CD}$$
  where the lower square and outer rectangle are pullback diagrams, if $X \to Y$ is a monomorphism, then $X' \to Y'$ is also a monomorphism.

Of course, both are true. In fact, the two are inter-derivable: the first one is a special case of the second (by taking $Y' \to S'$ and $Y \to S$ to be the identity), and you can deduce the second one from the first by using the pullback pasting lemma.